# Formatting Chemical Equations with mhchem in a list with Labels and Aligned Arrows in KaTeX

Tags: amsmath, enumerate, mhchem

I'm looking for assistance in formatting chemical equations to create a list that includes labels and aligns the equations by their arrows. Currently, I'm using the mhchem package for chemical equations and the amsmath package for aligning equations. While I'm familiar with these components individually, I'm unsure how to combine them effectively.

[image].

To create the equations as a list, I've employed the `enumitem` package with the following code

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Roman*}, labelsep=2em]
    \item \ce{NaCl(aq) + 3H2O(l) -> NaClO3(aq) + 3H2(g)}
    \item \ce{3NaOCl(aq) -> NaClO3(aq) + 2NaCl(aq)}
    \item \ce{NaClO3(aq) + KCl(aq) -> KClO3(aq) + NaCl(aq)}
\end{enumerate}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

On the other hand, to align the equations by their arrows, I've used the align environment:

```
\begin{align*}
   \ce{NaCl(aq) + 3H2O(l) &-> NaClO3(aq) + 3H2(g)} \\
   \ce{3NaOCl(aq) &-> NaClO3(aq) + 2NaCl(aq)} \\
   \ce{NaClO3(aq) + KCl(aq) &-> KClO3(aq) + NaCl(aq)}
\end{align*}
```

which produces

[image]
However, I'm struggling to combine both techniques. The `enumitem` package requires adding each equation as a separate item, making it challenging to utilize the align environment. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve the desired formatting, or if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community. You may try to use `flalign`  environment instead of `enumerate` ... BTW, providing of an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem, would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

See, if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
\mathbf{I}   &&  \ce{NaCl(aq) + 3H2O(l)   & -> NaClO3(aq) + 3H2(g)}     &   \\
\mathbf{II}  &&  \ce{3NaOCl(aq)           &-> NaClO3(aq) + 2NaCl(aq)}   &   \\
\mathbf{III} &&  \ce{NaClO3(aq) + KCl(aq) &-> KClO3(aq) + NaCl(aq)}     &
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @vyzee, you are welcome! BTW, if in the next few days you will not receive better answer, you may consider to accept mine (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on how to do this in KaTeX? I'm realizing that I don't think it supports flalign

Comment: @vyzee, sorry, I'm no familiar with `KaTeX`. If it support `amstex` then my solution should work even with it.

Comment: @vyzee, from your code fragments can be concluded, that KaTeX support math environments defined in `amsmath`. So, just try my example with use of `KaTeX` and see, what happens.

Comment: It definitely should but I keep getting a KaTeX parse error